# Where did the link only answer flag reason go?

Tags: support, flags, low-quality-posts, not-an-answer, link-only-answers

If I remember correctly, there used to be a "low quality" flag option for answers which would put them in the review queue to be deleted or commented on for being link only. I no longer see this option, where did it go?

[image: Flag dialog missing the low quality option]

The answer at the [suggested duplicate](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265552/when-to-flag-an-answer-as-it-is-not-an-answer) explicitly states not to use either of the close reasons for posts that attempt to answer the question, which leaves me puzzled. If the only option that remains is raising a a mod flag, then the commenting by reviewers has been removed from the system?

Comment: Very Low Quality is available if an answer is zero or negatively scored...

Comment: Cross-site duplicate: [Why is the option very low quality sometimes hidden in flag menu?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/258895/294055)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main thing to take away from [the linked post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265552/when-to-flag-an-answer-as-it-is-not-an-answer) is in [the accepted answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/265553/1380752)

> The rule-of-thumb here is to strip the markup; if you can still regard it as an (attempted) answer without the link, it is still an answer and should not be flagged.

so

> explicitly states not to use either of the close reasons for posts that attempt to answer the question

this is a bit confusing and I can see why. Did they *attempt* to answer? Yes, because they add a link to what they think would answer the question.

Is it an attempt to answer ***by SO standards***? No, not really because it is link only. So, yes it is an "attempt" but it is not actually an answer.

The answer linked to in that answer, [Your answer is in another castle](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer) does a great job of explaining all of this much better. So I would say that your post is better as a dupe of that one than the one suggested currently. But I wanted to give an answer to point out the confusion there.